# Sum Named Range over multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use a SUM formula over a multiple worksheets that are targetting the same Named Range **IP_Test**. My formula looks as following:

```
=SUM('Sheet1:Sheet3'!IP_Test)
```

The problem is, that this particular cell **IP_Test** defined withing every worksheet (it was *not* defined as a Workbook named range), is located on a different rows. Due to that I believe it gives me the **#NAME?** formula error.

Is there a way how to use **=SUM** formula with named ranges that are located on a different rows within every worksheet?

P.S. I may not use VBA for this particular case.

Comment: Can you put `=IP_Test` in a common, unused cell on all of the worksheets and sum that?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot as this Excel is used by other tool that is automatically importing all values. Due to that I may not add/remove any columns or rows, plus the data have very strict format where they have to be located; otherwise an error would occur. I can only used named ranges to simplify my calculations. Good idea though!

Comment: Try making it so that all Named Ranges refer to a cell in the same row and you will see that this is not the issue (you will still receive a #NAME? error). This 3D syntax is simply not valid with Named Ranges, I believe. I'm curious about your example: how many sheets are there between Sheet1 and Sheet3? Is this a variable?

Comment: I can temporarily create a new cell under every worksheet (as also Jeeped suggested) where I would place my temporary SUM formula for each sheet, and then simply reference this cell under SUMMARY sheet. Afterwards I can simply copy the formula and paste it as a value. Nonetheless I wanted to keep the formula, so that if user decides to do any change afterwards, the summary sheet will still give correct result. And there are total 3 sheets that I am summing at the moment; yet this number might grow in the future

Comment: If it's only 3 sheets, maybe you should simply use: `=SUM('Sheet1'!IP_Test,'Sheet2'!IP_Test,'Sheet3'!IP_Test)`

Comment: You actually gave me an idea in here! Thanks!

Comment: You could also use `=SUM(N(INDIRECT("Sheet" & {1,2,3} &"!IP_TEST")))`, or the same with a named range with all sheets names, but it's volatile, and still requires listing sheets somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

To quote from a comment by [@user3964075](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3964075/user3964075):

> =SUM(Sheet1!IP_Test,Sheet2!IP_Test,Sheet3!IP_Test)